# Iterate Over Many XML Attributes In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a XML file that has a series of attributes.  The attributes look something like the list below:

```
<Summary>
  <MyAttributes AT001="ABC" AT002="123" AT003="456" AT004="DEF" ... />
</Summary>
```

I need to iterate over the attributes and add them into a SQL table that looks something like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| AT001 | ABC |
| AT002 | 123 |
| AT003 | 456 |
| AT004 | DEF |
| ... | ... |

Because the attribute list isn't fixed, I need to iterate over all the attributes to ensure each attribute gets added.

I typically can figure out how to do things in SQL, but this one has me stumped!

Comment: What is your RDBMS and its version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what SQL you are using.

Here is how to do it in MS SQL Server by using its T-SQL and XQuery methods.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Summary>
  <MyAttributes AT001="ABC" AT002="123" AT003="456" AT004="DEF" />
</Summary>';

SELECT c.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS attr_name
    , c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS attr_value
FROM @xml.nodes('/Summary/MyAttributes/@*') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+------------+
| attr_name | attr_value |
+-----------+------------+
| AT001     | ABC        |
| AT002     | 123        |
| AT003     | 456        |
| AT004     | DEF        |
+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I'm using MS SQL Server.